# splitting a delimiter string but ignoring delimiter in quotes takes long time

Tags: java, split

I've a read a delimiter file in which I've to ignore the delimiter inside the quotes. 
I'm using

```
String stringArray[] = string.toString().split(columnSep+"(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
```

As record size increases the it is taking more time. Is there any way to optimize the split.

Please help

Comment: Please tag the question with the language you're using (Java?) to make it easier to find. What is the delimeter you're trying to use? What kind of quotation marks do you care about (e.g. single, double, 'smart' pairs)? Can quotation marks be escaped? If so a regular expression won't help you.

Comment: The delimiter might be comma or tab-delimited. It is double quotes. The string should be read from  a file and then process it